# Have I made a mistake in my For loop in python code? Model accuracy is too high so double checking

Tags: python, for-loop, logic, trading

I am building a quant model that takes a bunch of features and predicts performance of an index. The model is doing exceptionally well which obviously makes me wonder If I am making some mistake.

I have looked at the underlying features that I am using to ensure there is no data leakage. So now my attention is turning towards my code. Below is the main body of code that I use for prediction.

Does anything look wrong in the looping or how I am predicting? Please let me know if you need any more information and I will share what I can share.

- `X` -> Features used in model training and prediction
- `y` -> Class variable (1,0)
- `n_record` -> Number of records in the dataset
- `n_train` -> Amount of data to use for training in the rolling window construct
- `model` -> Ensemble model from sklearn

My training data is c4500 records. I used n_train of 800 to train the first instance of the model and then a rolling window of 800 for training to predict the 801st instance (and so on). So in that way I roll through time leaving out very old data (keeping the model "current").

```
col_names = ['Pred', 'Actual', 'Pred Prob'] #Column names for prediction output dataframe

def Strategy (n_train):
    list_ans = []
    n_records = len(X) #Number of records in X
    
    for i in range(n_train, n_records):
        # creating a rolling window to train model on backward data (n_train records) and predict tomorrows performance

        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[i-n_train:i], X[i:i+1], y[i-n_train:i], y[i:i+1]
        X_train = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test = ss.transform(X_test)
        
        model.fit(X_train,y_train)
        Pred=model.predict(X_test)
        Actual = y_test.values
        Prob = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
        
        i_ans = [Pred.item(), Actual.item(), Prob.item()]
        resi = pd.Series(data=i_ans, index=col_names)
        list_ans.append(resi)
        
        
    return pd.DataFrame(list_ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1. What values do you expect from `n_record` or `n_train`? keep in mind that `n_train` is acting as the `min` value for the range. I Don't know if this is how it should be, but be careful, you may be skipping training data.

Apart from that, it's good on my eyes!

Comment: Thank you! My training data is c4500 records. I used n_train of 800 to train the first instance of the model and then a rolling window of 800 for training to predict the 801st instance. So in that way I roll through time leaving out very old data (keeping the model "current").

Comment: Oh! in that case, it would be fine